# awk: 1: unexpected character ''' error

Tags: python, bash, awk, subprocess

I am trying to run this command via python subprocess

```
cat /etc/passwd | awk -F':' '{print $1}'
```

*What I did is ran the command by running two subprocess.*

1st: Which will fetch the result ie. **cat /etc/passwd**

2nd: The output of the first will be feed as input to the second **awk -F':' '{print $1}'**

**Here is the code:**

```
def executeCommand(self, command, filtercommand):
   cmdout = subp.Popen(command, stdout=subp.PIPE)
   filtered = subp.Popen(filtercommand, stdin=cmdout.stdout, stdout=subp.PIPE)
   output, err = filtered.communicate()
   if filtered.returncode is 0:
      logging.info("Result success,status code %d", filtered.returncode)
      return output
   else:
      logging.exception("ErrorCode:%d %s", filtered.returncode, output)
      return False
```

**Where,**

command=***['sudo', 'cat', '/etc/shadow']***

filtercommand=***['awk', "-F':'", "'{print $1}'", '|', 'uniq']***

**Error:**

```
awk: 1: unexpected character ''' error
```

**How I created the filercommand list that is passed to a function:**

```
filtercommand=["awk","-F\':\'", "\'{print $1}\'", '|', 'uniq']
```

Comment: There's no need for the single quotes in `"'{print $1}'"`. Simply remove them. Also, `"-F"` and `"':'"` must be two separate parameters, and the latter does not need single quotes, either.

Comment: Trying without single quotes throws `awk: cannot open | (No such file or directory)`

Comment: `|` is not a command line parameter, it is a shell redirection. You cannot use it this way. You must reconnect the stdout of `awk` to stdin of `uniq` the same way you reconnect the stdout of `cat` to stdin of `awk`. And by the way, you can do `sudo awk -F ':'  '{print $1}' /etc/shadow` without the `cat`.

Comment: ok I am using this `filtercommand=["awk","-F","\':\'", "{print $1}"]` and it work even though `"-F"` and `" ':' "` are not made or made separate. So I removed the | uniq to say ok let the duplicate also come BUT the result is not filtering on the basis of `:` delimiter though the result appears

Comment: As I said before, you do not need the single quotes around the separator :.

Comment: You can't use the last `filtercommand` with `shell=False` in the Popen constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a piped command directly using `subprocess.Popen` and get the output and error as this:

```
import subprocess

cmd = "cat /etc/passwd | awk -F':' 'NF>2 {print $1}'"

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate()

print output
print err
```

However note that `cat` is completely useless in above pipeline command since `awk` can directly operate on a file as this:

```
cmd = "awk -F':' 'NF>2 {print $1}' /etc/passwd"
```